# get_term or get_term_by is not working - I am outside the taxonomy nor inside a single.php

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

```
function sub_menu_industry_products_feat_func($atts) { 
      $atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'feat_img_slug' => ''), $atts ); 
      $term_id = $atts["feat_img_slug"]; 
      // term id is being fetched here .... 
      return get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, 'industry_product' )->name; 
  } 
  add_shortcode('sub_menu_industry_products_feat', 'sub_menu_industry_products_feat_func');
```

[image]

[image: what I want to accomplish]

[image: what I really really want to happen in detail]

[image: How to pull up the value handled by the ACF field using term id]

Comment: I am deeply sorry bro, first time to post stackoverflow after 10 yrs of using this platform, I have updated my query .... hope you can help :)

Comment: function sub_menu_industry_products_feat_func($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'feat_img_slug' => ''), $atts );
    $term_id = $atts["feat_img_slug"]; // term id is being fetched here ....
    return get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, 'industry_product' )->name;
} 
add_shortcode('sub_menu_industry_products_feat', 'sub_menu_industry_products_feat_func');

Comment: seems your code is correct. Need to check your taxonomy and ID are correct or not

Comment: @Vel Thanks a lot, My bad, I actually passed the wrong tag id :)

Comment: @Vel - could you help me pull the post meta value or value of the acf field which I assigned on the term taxanomy?, we know that term or category or sub category has no featured thumb image field that we can add, so we use ACF field and assigned it to the term ID any idea how we pull that up?

Comment: just use `$value = get_field( "text_field", 123 );` 123 is taxonomy id and  `text_field` is your ACF field name

Comment: I have tried that I guess, but does this apply outside the single.php since I want to query this in the mega menu? here is the sample https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEQC4.png

Comment: check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BgNr.png

Comment: @Vel I want to send you a badge how do I do this hehe

Comment: @Vel your awesome, I remember reading this, but I accidentally closed the browser sadly I was not able to pull that up again cause I set my browser to delete all history and cached cookies ... thanks mate!, I'll let you know if the screenshot you sent works out :)

Comment: Added that link in my answer. Please check that too. Accept the answer if its correct.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: @Vel thanks bro I commented down below and clicked the checked marked, your solution solved my problem, Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link about ACF plugin options. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

This example shows a variety of $post_id values to get a value from a post, user, term and option.

```
$post_id = false; // current post
$post_id = 1; // post ID = 1
$post_id = "user_2"; // user ID = 2
$post_id = "category_3"; // category term ID = 3
$post_id = "event_4"; // event (custom taxonomy) term ID = 4
$post_id = "option"; // options page
$post_id = "options"; // same as above

$value = get_field( 'my_field', $post_id );
```

Comment: Bro @vel vel - thanks a million it worked, I used the "$post_id = "event_4"; // event (custom taxonomy) term ID = 4" - and it pulled up the image url, sadly I can't upvote you as of the moment, cause my reputation is a bit low since I am a starter, I'll come back to upvote you when I have high reputation, Good bless mate :) - more power to you.

Comment: Glad to help you